# Apt package update is failing for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 18.04, software-sources, etc

sudo  apt update is failing ubuntu 18.04.

```
E: Release file for http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 11h 10min 58s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

E: Release file for http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 11h 11min 16s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 11h 10min 50s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

## source.list file Look like below

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: Check your system clock - it's most likely wrong (or timezone is incorrectly set)

Comment: Do you have an Internet connection, run rfkill unblock all; ip link

Comment: @hellomoto I have an internet connection and timezone also fixed. Still, the issue is coming.

Comment: I updated my answer, check whether it works.

Comment: you fixed timezone you said; is the clock correct?

Comment: @guiverc Clock is correct. Restarted the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have wrong timezone set, fix this or use this workaround below:

### Workaround

Add this to the command to `apt-get` commands:

```
-o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false
```

For example:

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Credits goes to [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-to-work-around-release-file-expired-problem-on-a-local-mirror).

### Edit:

If the workaround above did not work, then change your repository:

Go to *Settings->Softwares & Updates* and set *Download from* field to **Main Server**.

The cause of why it has happened maybe something is wrong with Indian Repository.

Comment: `-o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false` In which file Do I need to add this command?

Comment: Just do `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update`...

Comment: Followed your suggestion still, facing the same issue.

Comment: The Indian repos are working just fine for me.

Comment: @DKBose, in that case, maybe,  OP has messed up something with his timezone or repository. The idea of "something wrong with repository" I took here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/release-file-for-is-expired-915460/